# Need to reload JSON depending on window location hash

Tags: jquery, json

I am pulling from a JSON database and displaying a product based on its ID in a DIV. If the ID matches, it displays the correct item and its contents in the DIV.

I tried changing the logic to have it display a product based on if the product UPC matches the window.location.hash. This works for the first item but none of the others. So far no luck. Hoping someone can help me out with this. Below is my code thanks.

```js
var itemName = '';
var itemUPC = '';
var itemDesc = '';
var itemOZ = '';
var itemImage = '';

var compareHash = window.location.hash;
var compareUPC = '';

$.each(json, function(i, item) {

  compareUPC += '#' + item.itemFullUPC;

  if (compareHash == compareUPC) {

    itemName += '<h1>' + item.itemName + '</h1>';
    itemUPC += item.itemFullUPC;
    itemDesc += '<p>' + item.itemDescription + '</p>';
    itemOZ += '<h2>' + item.itemPackSize + '</p>';
    itemImage += '<img class="img-responsive img-rounded center-block" src="' + item.imageURL + '">';
  }

  $('#productTitle').html(itemName);
  $('#productUPC').html(strippedUPC);
  $('#productDescription').html(itemDesc);
  $('#productOZ').html(itemOZ);
  $('#productImage').html(itemImage);


});
```

Comment: Sample? += will concat the previous result with the new one...

Comment: @Nico what do you suggest i change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely want [onhashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange)

```
if ("onhashchange" in window) {
    alert("The browser supports the hashchange event!");
}

function locationHashChanged() {
     compareUPC += '#' + item.itemFullUPC; // or whatever you need to test here
     if (compareHash == compareUPC) {
        getJSON();
    }
}

// window.onhaschange=locationHashChanged; // or     
$(window).on("hashchange",locationHashChanged);
```

Comment: thank you this looks like it will work! the get JSON function you have is that where I would put the each loop?

Comment: yes :) - I assumed you also need to ajax the JSON or something in there